# WCF self-hosted web service using Kerberos authentication

Tags: web-services, wcf, kerberos

I'm trying to enable Kerberos authentication on a self-hosted RESTful WCF service.  I can see from the HTTP traffic that the client (I.e. Internet Explorer) correctly attempts a Kerberos authentication but for unknown reasons that Kerberos ticket is rejected by by my self-hosted service.  NTLM authentication is then successful, which I absolutely to not want.

Service Code:

```
var binding = new WebHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.InheritedFromHost;

var host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(TestService), new Uri(@"http://2008Web.ad.mdm.com:3456/testservice"));
ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), binding, "");
ep.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

ServiceAuthenticationBehavior sab = null;
sab = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceAuthenticationBehavior>();
sab.AuthenticationSchemes = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;

ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBeahvior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

host.Open();
```

This is the HTTP traffic observed:

```
adfsserver.ad.mdm.com   2008WEB                    HTTP:Request, GET /testservice/Test 
2008WEB                 adfsserver.ad.mdm.com      HTTP:Response, HTTP/1.1, Status: Unauthorized, URL: /testservice/Test , Using Negotiate Authentication 
adfsserver.ad.mdm.com   2008WEB                    HTTP:Request, GET /testservice/Test , Using GSS-API Authorization  (****Kerberos Ticket in header*****)
2008WEB                 adfsserver.ad.mdm.com      HTTP:Response, HTTP/1.1, Status: Unauthorized, URL: /testservice/Test , Using GSS-API Authentication 
adfsserver.ad.mdm.com   2008WEB                    HTTP:Request, GET /testservice/Test , Using GSS-API Authorization  (****NTLM Ticket in header*****)
2008WEB                 adfsserver.ad.mdm.com      HTTP:Response, HTTP/1.1, Status: Ok, URL: /testservice/Test , Using oRswGaADCgEAoxIEEAEAAABdREAy5JJFLAAAAAA= Authentication
```

I have tried to register the SPN (Service Principal Name) as:

```
setspn -s host/2008Web:3456 2008Web
setspn -s host/2008Web.ad.mdm.com:3456 2008Web
setspn -s http/2008Web:3456 administrator
setspn -s http/2008Web.ad.mdm.com:3456 administrator
setspn -s http/2008Web:3456/testservice administrator
setspn -s http/2008Web.ad.mdm.com:3456/testservice administrator
```

Neither the Windows event log nor WCF logging provide any indication as to why the Kerberos authentication is failing.

When I host the same service in IIS, Kerberos authentication works fine.  Furthermore, I never had to register (or identify) a SPN when hosting the service in IIS, it just works.  It wasn't until I started searching for this issue that individuals talked about a SPN. I've never had to worry about SPNs before and I've used several IIS hosted Kerberos enabled web services in the past.

What's the secret sauce?  What am I missing?  I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.  Is there any other logs I can examine/enable to hopefully identity why the HTTP stack has decided to pitch the Kerberos request on the floor?  There must be some way of determining why this is failing.

I'm pretty sure that this problem has nothing to do with Server Principal Name as I can see that the domain controller does grant a Kerberos ticket.  On the domain controller I do not see KRB5KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN but rather TGS-REP (granting the Kerberos ticket).  Furthermore, I see the Kerberos ticket in the HTTP request at the server.  Thus, the problem must be with the WCF self-hosted service.

Using a Kerberos enabled iOS7 app, I see a slightly different network trace.  I see the domain controller grant the Kerberos ticket to the iOS7 app and then I see the Kerberos ticket presented to the WCF Service (at the HTTP level).  However, the response from the WCF service (at the HTTP level) is HTTP 400, Bad Request.  From what I read, HTTP 400 usually has to do with an issue on the client side.  That is, it is presenting a HTTP packet in a format that is not supported by the HTTP server end.  With all that being said, like the IE example above, everything works fine when the WCF service is hosted in IIS.  There is ZERO information in the WCF logging (it never makes it to that level as it is rejected by the HTTP stack) and there is ZERO information associated with this event in the event log.

Is there something I'm missing in the above configuration of the WCF service?  What you see above is all that there is.  That is, I am not using the application configuration file to configure this WCF service.  The WCF service is being configured programmatically.  If I remove the authentication configuration, then everything works fine.  The iOS7 app, Safari, and IE can all successfully interact with my self-hosted WCF service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After no help from the usual debugging tools (http error log, event viewer, WCF logging, etc.) I discovered what the issue was.  As discussed above, I could see the kerberos ticket arrive at the server (wire stark) but then the request was denied.  I speculated that the http header may have exceeded the maximum length.  I found the following article:

[Kerberos authentication failing with 401](https://serverfault.com/questions/470323/kerberos-authentication-failing-with-401)

After adjusting the following http registry settings, kerberos authentication started to work:

```
MaxRequestBytes - set to 1048576
MaxFieldLength - set to 65534
```

While the following article didn't directly help me with my issue, perhaps someone will find some value in it:

[Things to check when Kerberos authentication fails using IIS/IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2009/12/31/things-to-check-when-kerberos-authentication-fails-using-iis-ie.aspx)